# How to change QListWidget size interactively

Tags: python, pyqt

There are two questions regarding this example (Qt Gui).

Question 1: Even while every possible margin has been set to zero (using `.setSpacing()` and `.setContentsMargins()` methods there is still a space around the QPushButton. What widget and attribute is responsible for the extra space around button?

Question 2: Is there a way to make QListWidgets "re-sizable"? (so the user could clic a "divider" and drag it left-right interactively making one ListWidget wider and another thinner without changing a size of dialog window - keeping the window size consistent).
[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class MyApp(object):    
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()                
        self.mainWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.mainWidget.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.mainWidget.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        self.hLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.insertLayout(0, self.hLayout)
        self.listA=QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.listB=QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.listA)
        self.hLayout.addWidget(self.listB)

        self.buttonGroupbox = QtGui.QGroupBox()
        self.buttonlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.buttonGroupbox.setLayout(self.buttonlayout)

        self.buttonGroupbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.buttonlayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.buttonlayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        self.okButton = QtGui.QPushButton('OK')
        self.buttonlayout.addWidget(self.okButton)
        self.okButton.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0) 

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.buttonGroupbox)
        self.mainWidget.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyApp()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question maybe you could obtain your target layout with a button stylesheet setting

```
self.okButton.setStyleSheet('padding: 0px;')
```

For second one you have to substitute QHBoxLayout with QSplitter

```
self.splitter = QtGui.QSplitter()
self.listA = QtGui.QListWidget()
self.listB = QtGui.QListWidget()
self.splitter.addWidget(self.listA)
self.splitter.addWidget(self.listB)
self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.splitter)
```

Results are showed in the following picture

[image]